# How can I test my php application in slow connection

Tags: php, apache, testing

I am developing a php web application. I want to test how it will behave under slow connection So I am asking if I can slow down apache server  to simulate slow processing or to slowing down network connection .

Is this a good idea and how ? Or any other ideas about such issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you have to the ability to simulate network speed. Open the developer tools and click on the phone icon on the left. Now at the top you have some network options. (WiFi, GPRS...)